# copy a range to a defined array

Tags: excel, vba

how to copy a range to a already defined array?

```
Dim l1(71, 6) As Variant
l1 = wsTEMP.Range("g3:m72").Value
```

this does not work!

Answer (score 1):

If you wnt to retain the dimensions you've declared the array at, resize the source according to the initial array.

```
Dim l1(1 to 71, 1 to 6) As Variant

l1 = wsTEMP.Range("g3").resize(ubound(l1 , 1), ubound(l1 , 2)).Value
```

Stuffing worksheet cells into a variant array **always** creates a one-based, 2-D array. You cannot change that.